# Proper record not displaying for data needed in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, inner-join, where-clause

I have a requirement where I want to show the relevant data which should not be greater than 6 months from todays date. SO I wrote the below query for the same but it is showing me the data of `2019` also.

```
select CR.CHANGEREQUESTID ,CR.CHANGEREQUESTNUMBER, CR.STATENAME, CR.NETWORKTYPE, CR.CREATEDON, 
CR.LASTMODIFIEDON,
NHQ.SAP_ID, NHQ.STATE, NHQ.NEW_LATITUDE, NHQ.NEW_LONGITUDE, NHQ.OLD_LATITUDE, NHQ.OLD_LONGITUDE
from CHANGEREQUESTS CR
inner join TBL_NHQ_CIRCLE_INFO NHQ
on CR.CHANGEREQUESTID = NHQ.CHNGREQUEST_ID
where CR.lastmodifiedon > add_months(sysdate, -12)
and CR.CHANGETYPEID=55;
```

Please suggest what is wrong here.

Comment: **6** months vs. add_months(sysdate, -**12**)?

Comment: @Littlefoot: i changed 12 to 6 but still there are dates of year 2019..!!

Comment: @hud: That doesn't seem likely. Maybe your system time is completely wrong? Which date does `select sysdate from dual;` return?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: It returns as `07-12-20`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This condition gives you all record that are less than 1 year old:

```
where CR.lastmodifiedon > add_months(sysdate, -12)
```

If you wanted records older than 6 month, that would be:

```
where CR.lastmodifiedon < add_months(sysdate, -6)
```

On the other hand, if you want dates between 6 months ago and today:

```
where CR.lastmodifiedon > add_months(sysdate, -6) and  CR.lastmodifiedon <= sysdate
```

Comment: I am still able to view one record whose lastmodifieddate is `23-09-2019`

Comment: @hud: well, that date is older than 6 months, so it does satisfy the condition...

Comment: NO, my requirement is. I want the data of dates within 6 months from the current date

Comment: Thanks that worked...! I did silly mistake with `<` and `>` signs